# angularjs infinity scroll in a div

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

i try to add infinity scroll in a div . but it not work . I Shaw some solution here 
[angularjs infinite scroll in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674266/angularjs-infinite-scroll-in-a-container)

But this solutions are not work for me .

My div

```
<div id="main_pro_content" role="main_pro_content" infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'></div>
```

Comment: Why is it not working for you? I know the library you are using, it's written terribly but it works.

Comment: its not working in div . i try this one <div infinite-scroll="addPage()" infinite-scroll-container='".content"'>