# AngularJS ng-infinite-scroll not working on a specific container/div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginfinitescroll

I wrote this code after reading multiple posts about ng-infinite-scroll

```
<div class="course-enrollment-friends" ng-class="{'friends-paginated':showMoreFriends}">
    <div class="row" id="enrollment-friends" ng-show="!noFriends">
        <div
         infinite-scroll="enrollCtrl.retYearAndSem()"
         infinite-scroll-disabled='!{{showMoreFriends}}'
         infinite-scroll-parent='true'>
            <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="friend in friends" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
```

**However this didn't work.** So I tried something slightly different

```
<div class="course-enrollment-friends" ng-class="{'friends-paginated':showMoreFriends}">
    <div class="row" id="enrollment-friends" ng-show="!noFriends">
        <div
         infinite-scroll="enrollCtrl.retYearAndSem()"
         infinite-scroll-disabled='!{{showMoreFriends}}'
         infinite-scroll-container='.course-enrollment-friends'>
            <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="friend in friends" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't find any reference to `infinite-scroll-container='.course-enrollment-friends'` in the docs. Where's that from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28521884/5088332

Answer (score 0):

From the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28521884/5088332), it seems you forgot the double quotes:

> The value of infinite-scroll-container in this example **is
>   double-quoted** class name .content then wrapped by single quotes. If
>   you read the source, the string value eventually gets fed into
>   document.querySelector. You can read the documentation on that to see
>   what value it expects.

Without the double quotes `.course-enrollment-friends` is passed in as a variable name, not as a string as is required.

So

```
infinite-scroll-container='".course-enrollment-friends"'
```

instead of

```
infinite-scroll-container='.course-enrollment-friends'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. While I was hopeful that you caught the issue, it still didn't work... I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the divs somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the braces around the value given in infinite-scroll-disabled. Use:

```
<div
     infinite-scroll="enrollCtrl.retYearAndSem()"
     infinite-scroll-disabled='!showMoreFriends'
     infinite-scroll-container='.course-enrollment-friends'>
```

instead of :

```
<div
     infinite-scroll="enrollCtrl.retYearAndSem()"
     infinite-scroll-disabled='!{{showMoreFriends}}'
     infinite-scroll-container='.course-enrollment-friends'>
```