# ngInfiniteScroll not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I am trying to make ngInfiniteScroll work but in vain - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4V0ZYkqE3yEmQce5rh76?p=preview). Scroll event is only triggered on page load, after that nothing seems to trigger it. Can anyone please shed some light.

I tried various combinations, none worked:

```
infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2' infinite-scroll-container="'#list-wrapper'" 

infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2' infinite-scroll-parent

infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'
```

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="listController">
      <div id="list-wrapper">
          <div class="list" infinite-scroll='loadMore()' 
        infinite-scroll-distance='2' 
        infinite-scroll-container="'#list-wrapper'">
            <div class="header">

            </div>

            <div class="list-table" >
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in infiniteList">
                            <td style="width:100%">
                                <div>{{item}}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style='clear: both;'></div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['infinite-scroll']);

app.controller('listController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.infiniteList = [];
    $scope.incr = 1;

    $scope.loadMore = function(){
      console.log("scroll");
        for(var i = 0; i< 30; i++){
            $scope.infiniteList.push("Item " + $scope.incr);
            $scope.incr +=1;
        }
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT: you are using the latest stable version of ngInfinite Scroll, which does not have the -container and -parent methods, i have update the plunker with the develpoment ngInfiniteScroll.js, now you can see the working code here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Bs9RYXhSAPhmQG5M6pyg?p=preview

OLD:

> ngInfiniteScroll will call myPagingFunction() any time the bottom of
>   the element approaches the bottom of the browser window

so, if you change your css and remove the max-height, so that the list covers the page,you will see that the infinitescroll is working when user scrolls past the page.

```
#list-wrapper{
    //max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;

    margin-top: 20px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/aaUWnnKoH9kXGFx70U2J?p=preview

also see: [angularjs infinite scroll in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674266/angularjs-infinite-scroll-in-a-container)

Comment: I had some trouble with this issue, I didn't even check the version number, cause I have gotten the js files from nuget, so I supposed they were the latest version, but they were from 2013. changing the file content with the latest code, and changing as in your example fixed the issue

Answer (score 4):

Check your MAIN HTML or body tag. They might be containing some overflow css. So the page scroll must be the wrapper in that case.

```
body {
height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and

```
    <div infinite-scroll='getMoreListingData()' infinite-scroll-disabled='isbusy'
     infinite-scroll-distance='0'
     infinite-scroll-container="'body'">
```

This saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

You can checkout the 1.3.0 version, which performs a check for "infinite-scroll-parent".

If you are using bower: **bower install --save ngInfiniteScroll#1.3.0**

```
<div class="scroll-container"> <!-- Fixed height is OK -->
    <div infinite-scroll="vm.notifications.loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance='1' infinite-scroll-immediate-check='true' infinite-scroll-parent="true">
```